# Sources for quantum cryptography and post quantum cryptography

Tags: resource-request, cryptography

I am a beginner in quantum computing, and I understand the basics of quantum computing.

Can anyone suggest me a beginners material for quantum cryptography and post quantum cryptography? Book, Video or lecture notes, anything will do, given it is good for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an online video lecture course given by Stephanie Wehner and Thomas Vidick that gives a fairly nice overview of quantum cryptography. You can find the course [here](https://ocw.tudelft.nl/courses/quantum-cryptography/#1493321998511-d275a9fe-1528).

Answer (score 2):

I would recomend reading article [Experimental Quantum Cryptography](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00191318) by, inter alia, Charles Bennett, one of inventor of BB84 protocol. Especially first chapter on history and second chapter on quantum key distribution are accessible even to beginer in QC.